# YearMonth datequery

Tags: query, date, parameter

I'm trying to make use of the Date Parameter 'm' which is for the YearMonth. I can't figure out what the query name is or how to use it to search for posts with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for posts based on date, you can set up a quick instance of WP_Query. The best place to look is the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/), and in particular the section on the [date parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters).

A basic search for posts in a particular month will look a little like this:

```
<?php

$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'm' => '201607', // will return posts in July 2016
  'posts_per_page' => '10', // lets get only the latest 10 posts
  'post_type' => 'post', // you can set this to a different post type if needed
  'post_status' => 'publish', // 'published' posts only, not draft/private etc.
) );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
        // whatever else about the post you want to output :)
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata(); // restore original post data, since custom queries modify it

?>
```

As described in the documentation I linked to, you can also use parameters `year` and `monthnum`, or even return multiple months and years at the same time using a slightly more complicated `date_query` (examples are in the documentation).

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot to write the date out as a string and it works now XD